# Is Niddah considered to be gilui arayos for purposes of martyrdom?

Tags: halacha, niddah, arayot, martyr

Gilui Arayos as is known is one of the 3 "big avaros" that one has to give up their life for. Is the prohibition of a Niddah considered forbidden to the extent that one would have to give up one's life to avoid violating such a prohibition?

Update: Since there seems to be a discussion in this I'd like to pose another question. According to the one that holds it's not in the category of gilui arayos is it possible still that a niddah is still considered to be an "ervah"? Or do the 2 for sure go along (I heard this point discussed by someone and seems there would be nafkah minas. A possibility would be that we say ein davar sheberva pachos mishnayim, however by a niddah the isha herself is believed -- eid echad.)

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%94#.D7.91.D7.9E.D7.A7.D7.95.D7.9D_.D7.A1.D7.9B.D7.A0.D7.94

Comment: There is a notable difference to usual giluim arayos - the children produced from such unions are mamzerim, but for niddah it's a dispute between R' Akiva (who says the child is a mamzer) and the Chachomim (who say he is not), and we paskin like the chachomim.

Comment: @gt6989b Rabbi Akiva says _lavin_ make a mamzer but I don't think he says that about Niddah too.

Comment: @DoubleAA I haven't learned it in a while, but I do remember learning that it was his opinion at some point in the past.

Comment: @DoubleAA I would like to ask an additional question as well that even according to those that say a niddah is not b'clal "gilui arayos" if there is room to say that a niddah is b'clal "ervah"? Whatever the nafkeh minah might be (I heard someone today being "choker" in this.)

Comment: @Yehoshua You have a good question, but your terminology is too loose. Arayos is just the plural form of erva.

Comment: @DoubleAA The point was is that there is some nafka minah if the niddah is an "ervah" howver still wouldn't be b'clal the dinim of gilui arayos (giving up ones life, etc)

Comment: @Yehoshua I understand and you have a good point, but your terminology is too loose. Where did you come up with this category of gilui arayos that all have the same dinim? There are lots of dinim related to issurei biah (mamzer, kiddushin, yichud, negia, ein davar sheberva pachot mishnayim, context in psukim, kiddush hashem, potrin tzarot meichalitza) and you have to analyze them all separately. Some may have to do with shem erva, or maaseh erva, or because of karet, or chillul hashem etc. Erva and Arayot are the same word. You have to be clearer what category you are comparing niddah to.

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps we could start with the point of "ein davar sheberva pachos mishnayim" ... By Niddah we believe the isha herself (one person.)

Comment: @Yehoshua That's rabbeinu tam's point :)

Comment: @DoubleAA where is this discussed? And what does he hold about the idea of gilui arayos

Comment: @Yehoshua Sefer Hayashar 80

Answer (score 5):

[Torah Lishma Question 494](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20829&st=&pgnum=358&hilite=) concludes that it is not something one should get killed for.

Comment: @DoubleAA I dont think this mechaber is reliable at all. A quarter page tshuva over a machlokes haposkim when he doesnt bring anyone at all.

Comment: @GershonGold It isn't a very convincing Teshuva, even if he knew it all in his head. You certainly can't blame anyone for saying such a thing about someone if all they had to base themselves on was this Teshuva.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9249261#9249261

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13554/759

Comment: @AlBerko it's disputed if he wrote it

Comment: @DoubleAA I put it because of the date, to know where to plot the answer - Rishonim, Achronim, latest?

Comment: @AlBerko I know